# CSS + images not working on github pages but is working locally

Tags: html, css, github-pages

I don't know if it has to do with me trying and failing to work a custom domain from hover or what is going on but here is my import.

Everything works and looks amazing on my local preview but when I try to bring it over to anthematics.github.io just the HTML works. The images and the CSS does not load.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="theme.css" type="text/css">
```

`theme.css` is in root and I did it without the / at first until I started having issues.

Comment: For me images and styling are loaded. Check the developer console for errors, especially the network tab may contain errors if files are not being loaded. Check whether the URL is correct or what the server response looks like.

Comment: What? I can see it is working :/

Comment: Maybe this happened when you just uploaded the files a second ago and the server didn't realise they were there yet?

Comment: It was a caching thing I think because you're right !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a caching issue - I cannot mark comments as answers so I am putting it here - if you come across this try Devtools - network - disable cache - then clear your cache on your browser.